# How to get all tables owned by one user but not by others, one by one

Tags: sql, database, oracle

It's being assumed that two users own the same table when both of them own a table with the same name each.

In my Oracle Database, I have N users called MAIN, USR_1, USR_2, ..., USR_N. The user MAIN owns all tables that others users have. However, it might have a table that USR_1 owns but USR_2 not, or USR_2048 owns and USR_1024 not, and so on.

I'd like to make a query which retrieves all tables that are owned by MAIN user but not by a certain user. In fact, I would like to check one by one, something like:

Get all tables owned by user MAIN and compares it with USR_1,
Get all tables owned by user MAIN and compares it with USR_2,
...
Get all tables owned by user MAIN and compares it with USR_N,

And return the table name which is contained by MAIN but not by this certain user.

I have tried doing both:

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
  FROM DBA_TABLES
 WHERE OWNER LIKE 'MAIN'
   AND TABLE_NAME NOT IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME
                            FROM DBA_TABLES
                           WHERE OWNER LIKE '%USR_%');
```

```
SELECT TABLE_NAME
  FROM DBA_TABLES
 WHERE OWNER LIKE 'MAIN'
   AND TABLE_NAME NOT IN (SELECT TABLE_NAME
                            FROM DBA_TABLES
                           WHERE OWNER LIKE '%USR_%'
                           GROUP BY OWNER, TABLE_NAME);
```

I understand why the first statement doesn't work, but I thought it'd be possible to work with the second one. How could I make it possible?

Comment: You seem to have `LIKE` and `=` mixed up? `%` wildcard matching does not work with `=`

Comment: @kfinity, you're right. I just copied it wrong, thanks!

Comment: A table in Oracle database always has exactly **one** owner. Please clarify your question. Do you mean "tables with the same name, owned by different users"? If so, note that a table `students` owned by one user may have absolutely nothing to do (different columns, different data, etc.) with a table `students` owned by another user.

Comment: Exactly what you said. Sorry if the question wasn't that clear at first glance. I'll try to make it better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
SELECT m.TABLE_NAME, usr_count, owner_list
  FROM DBA_TABLES m
LEFT JOIN (SELECT TABLE_NAME, count(*) as usr_count, listagg(OWNER, ',') within group (order by OWNER) as owner_list
             FROM DBA_TABLES
            WHERE OWNER LIKE 'USR_%'
            GROUP BY TABLE_NAME) usr
ON m.TABLE_NAME = usr.TABLE_NAME
 WHERE m.OWNER LIKE 'MAIN'
  -- hide tables that everyone has
  AND coalesce(usr_count,0) < (select count(*) from ALL_USERS where USERNAME like 'USR_%') 
;
```

Edit: Actually, if you want a list of the USR_% users who *don't* have each table, an anti-join might be better.

```
SELECT m.TABLE_NAME, listagg(USERNAME, ',') within group (order by USERNAME) as usr_missing_table
  FROM DBA_TABLES m
JOIN ALL_USERS a
  ON a.USERNAME like 'USR_%'
LEFT JOIN DBA_TABLES usr
  ON a.USERNAME = usr.OWNER
  AND m.TABLE_NAME = usr.TABLE_NAME
WHERE m.OWNER LIKE 'MAIN'
  AND usr.TABLE_NAME is null
GROUP BY m.TABLE_NAME
;
```

Comment: May also be done with a single use of `dba_tables` by adding `MAIN` to the filter and 1 to the user count

Comment: Oh, good point - if we're assuming that all USR_% table names also exist in MAIN schema.